# Firefox-esr is still at v60.9.0. When will it be updated?

Tags: raspbian-buster, web-browsers

I have just installed firefox-esr on buster and it reports it is v60.9.0esr.  The latest released 32bit esr version is 68. Why is Raspbian so far behind and when will it catch up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=248269#p1519528), you can directly install Firefox ESR on Raspbian through [debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/), so, follow the procedure:

**1.** Download the package:

```
wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/f/firefox-esr/firefox-esr_68.3.0esr-1~deb10u1_armhf.deb
```

**2.** Install the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i firefox-esr_68.3.0esr-1~deb10u1_armhf.deb
```

If you find a problem, try this .deb file.
https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20190714T155055Z/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_68.0-3_armhf.deb

Done.

Comment: Many thanks, that worked no problem.

Comment: @WhyNine Alright, Accept if the answer is a solution for you.